# Launcher tooltip occasionally goes missing

Tags: 12.04, launcher, tooltip

The tooltip that appears when you mouseover applications in the launcher sometimes goes missing or doesn't show the application name correctly. Is it possible to repair this problem?

This is the screenshot of my problem.

[image: http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/4973/screenshotfrom201208261.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug:      [Bug #1034164 : [SRU Regression] Unity 5.14 + Nux 2.14: Launcher tooltips are incomplete/missing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1034164)

The ppa `ppa:unity-team/sru` contains a fix.

Comment: how to add the repository for this bug

Answer (score 0):

To add that to repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/sru
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Worked like a charm for me...

Comment: **Note**: `unity-team/sru` are *unsupported packages* and can potentially cause undesired effects.